# Error during data import to Mariadb 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I exported my database using PHPMyAdmin running Mariadb 10. Now when I try to import the .sql file in another server running Mariadb 10. The import freezes at some point. After debugging, I realise it freezes at the queries below:

```
--
-- Indexes for table `user_jobs`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_jobs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_jobs_queue_reserved_reserved_at_index` (`queue`,`reserved`,`reserved_at`);


--
-- Indexes for table `account_jobs`
--
ALTER TABLE `account_jobs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `jobs_queue_reserved_reserved_at_index` (`queue`,`reserved`,`reserved_at`);
```

Removing the above from the .sql file, the import runs successfully.

Now when I manually execute the above queries, there run successfully.

Why doesn't this work during the import?

I don't get any special error except that the import just hangs looking at me until I would have to end the process using Ctrl+C

Appreciate help!

Comment: You are saying the total time for the two steps (load data + add indexes) is significantly different depending on how you run the steps?  Or are you saying that one method has a 'hidden' timelimit that does not let it finish?

Comment: How big are the tables?  What Engine is being used?

Comment: Hi @Rick James. The tables are not big. Infact there is currently no data on these tables. What I mean is when I run `source cms.sql`, the import process freezes at some point. When I open the cms.sql and removed those queries, the import execute to end successfully.

Comment: However when I execute the above queries manually, they execute successfully so I don't understand why it doesn't execute during the import process. When the import reaches the line where these queries start, it doesn't continue even if you wait for a long time. Manually they execute in few seconds.

Comment: Is `cms.sql` 20 lines long?  Or 20 million lines?

Comment: Do you have quotes or apostrophes in the "bad" lines?  (Please delete the redundant Comments.)  Please show us those lines (or at least the first few).

Comment: Hi @RickJames. The lines in my question.

Comment: OK, but how big is the table?  (The `ALTER` will take a long time -- the bigger the table, the longer.)

Comment: Hi @Rick James, If by big you mean the number of records, the table currently has no data

Comment: Sounds like a bug.